# Regex to extract numbers from a recipe

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to extract all numbers(integers and decimals) from a .txt file for a mobile recipe app(I'm using Android Studio with Java). I want to extract all numbers except numbers like 180°C, 190 °C, 6hours, 6 hours, 5minutes, 5 minutes(i.e. any number execpt ones with °C or hour/s minute/s and second/s suceeding the number with or without a space)

I would also like to extrat the word after the number match as a sepreate match, so for 3 eggs match 3 and eggs and for 10ml milk match 10 and milk but do not match 180°C and 6 minutes.

The goal of all this is to let the user enter the number of times the user wants to make the recipe, say 2 and then update all the ingrients too twice the original recipe, but leave the 180°C and say 30 minutes as obivously 360°C and 60 minutes is incorrect?

Thank you in advance

I got the ingredients list to work with:

```
.*?([\\d.]+).*
```

for the number and:

```
[0-9.]
```

for the ingredients as there is only 1 ingredient per line.

I'm struggling to get the "Method" part of the recipe to work(say when a recipe says use 2 of the 4 eggs in the Method). I have the following regex:

```
(?<!°C)(?<!hour)(?<!minute)(?<!minutes)\\b\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\b(?!\\s*(°C|hour|minute|minutes))
```

it works the problem is it matches 10 in "10 ml milk" but not "10ml milk" and I have no idea how to get milk then to match?

Comment: Do you realize that all `(?<!°C)(?<!hour)(?<!minute)(?<!minutes)` lookbehinds are unnecessary, since you have a word boundary right after them. You can just remove them,  and the second word boundary - `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\s*(?:°C|hours?|minutes?))` - https://regex101.com/r/X1ozE9/1

Answer (score 1):

try using: `"((\\d+?(/\\d+)?)\\s?(m?l|cups?|teaspoon|tablespoon)?)\\s(?![°C]|hours?|minutes?|seconds?)(\\b\\w+\\b)"`

use this for detection decimals:
`"((\d+?(\.\d+)?)\s?(m?l|cups?|teaspoon|tablespoon)?)\s(?![°C]|hours?|minutes?|seconds?)(\b\w+\b)"`

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // use this for detecting decimals, but not fractions.
        // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\d+?(\\.\\d+)?)\\s?(m?l|cups?|teaspoon|tablespoon)?)\\s(?![°C]|hours?|minutes?|seconds?)(\\b\\w+\\b)");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\d+?(/\\d+)?)\\s?(m?l|cups?|teaspoon|tablespoon)?)\\s(?![°C]|hours?|minutes?|seconds?)(\\b\\w+\\b)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("3 eggs 1cup flour 1/2 cup sugar 1 hour 50 minutes 1/2teaspoon salt minutes of salt 30ml milk");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            System.out.println("number match: " + matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println("Cups/ml/teaspoon match: " + matcher.group(4));
            System.out.println("ingredient match: " + matcher.group(5));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Full match: 3 eggs
number match: 3
Cups/ml/teaspoon match: null
ingredient match: eggs

Full match: 1cup flour
number match: 1
Cups/ml/teaspoon match: cup
ingredient match: flour

Full match: 1/2 cup sugar
number match: 1/2
Cups/ml/teaspoon match: cup
ingredient match: sugar

Full match: 1/2teaspoon salt
number match: 1/2
Cups/ml/teaspoon match: teaspoon
ingredient match: salt

Full match: 30ml milk
number match: 30
Cups/ml/teaspoon match: ml
ingredient match: milk
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, this is excatly what I needed. When I use your code instead of getting 0.333 I get 333, is there a way to get 0.333. The code I'm using is this:                  this.Amount.add(Float.valueOf(matcher.group(2)));                                                                            To test were the regex is matching I'm using:                                                                                 textView.append(matcher.group(2) +matcher.group(4)+ matcher.group(5) + "\n");                       Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: then we can change the regex to
"((\\d+?(\\.\\d+)?)\\s?(m?l|cups?|teaspoon|tablespoon)?)\\s(?![°C]|hours?|minutes?|seconds?)(\\b\\w+\\b)"

but now the regex will no longer be able to recognize 2/3 or any other fractions

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. If I want to add other mesurments say "kg" and "g" do I just add it like "....|teaspoon|tablespoon|kg|g)?....", and other exclusions like "ure" and "uur" (hours and hour in Afrikaans) like "....|minutes?|seconds?|ure?|uur?)...." ?

Comment: yes, you can just append it like that.

Comment: I saw some recipes use "2L (8 cups) of milk", is there a way to get a match for "2L of milk" and "2L (8 cups) of milk"?